# Check if non axis-aligned bounding box contains another one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, bounding-box

I work with Unity3D and want to check for neighbouring meshes next to a given mesh.

The problem is, Unity's bounding boxes are axis-aligned, so after rotation, they look like the first image below and are considered neighbours.

[image: Image1]

I want them to look like this:

[image: Image2]

How can I achieve this and how to get objects and calculate intersections of the two boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bounding box is always world-axis-aligned. A non-aligned box is just a box.

---

With that distincton made, you can use several methods to check if volumes intersect other volumes and/or points. Here are some:

- [Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html)
- [Physics.BoxCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html)
- [Collider.ClosestPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html)
- OnTrigger... methods from [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)